# How to implement a rename function for a HTTP based file server?

Tags: http, httpfs

I have to implement a HTTP server with some file server capabilities.
I'd already coded HTTP HEAD, GET, PUT, and DELETE requests.

Next thing I need to implement something like RENAME or MOVE to change the name of a file which is already stored on the server. But I cannot find an appropriate HTTP request method for this.

Any idea how to do this or might that be not possible?

Answer (score 1):

Found [WebDAV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebDAV) extensions which added a matching HTTP method `MOVE` for this.

- https://tech.yandex.com/disk/doc/dg/reference/move-docpage
- http://www.qed42.com/blog/using-curl-commands-webdav

There is also a method `MKCOL` to create a directory.